# Cannot obtain boolean value from this Asynch operation using Swift 5.3

Tags: swift, asynchronous

The following code attached will process the print statements (success, no success) but I cannot set or use the function outside of update status. Can someone provide an example of how I can get the Bool for the return (not just hardcoding it to true)?

```
    func updateStatus( completion: @escaping (_ flag:Bool) -> ()) {
        //let retVal: Bool = true
        let url = URL(string: build())! //"http://192.168.1.4:6875/login")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            if error != nil || data == nil {
                print("Client error!")
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                print("Server error!")
                completion(false)
                return
            }

            guard let mime = response.mimeType, mime == "text/html" else {
                print("Wrong MIME type!")
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            
            print("Yay! Everything is working!")
            completion(true)
            
            print(data!)
            
/*
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
 */
        }
        task.resume()
        //return retVal
    }

    func ping() -> Bool {
        updateStatus { success in
            if success {
                print("success")
            } else {
                print("not sucess!")
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Pass a completion handler to `ping` and have it do whatever it needs to with the `success` results.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone provide an example of how I can get the Bool for the return (not just hardcoding it to true)?

You can't. Your `success` arrives *asynchronously* in a *completion handler*. You cannot return anything that depends on it. You must do exactly the same thing you did with `updateStatus`, and for the self-same reason — your code is asynchronous, so in order to do anything with its results, you must call into a *completion handler*.

In short, the completion handler pattern propagates asynchronousness. You cannot magically stop propagating it.

---

Basically, your mistake here is that `ping` is trying to do two different things at two different times: it wants to *start* the asynchronous activity (by calling `updateStatus`) and function as the *end* of the asynchronous activity (by returning a Bool). But it cannot do both, because those things happen at two different times; the activity is *asynchronous*, so the Bool is returned *before* the activity even starts.

Comment: I should just add that starting in iOS 13 there is another way to propagate asynchronousness coherently, namely to use the Combine framework. That is in fact what I now prefer. It makes the relationship between starting the asynchronous action and receiving its result a lot clearer. The problem with your `ping` is that it tries to be at both the start and at the end of the asychronous action, and that is impossible unless you have a wormhole in the fabric of the universe.

Comment: Whereas, with Combine, you have a _pipeline_ with a definite start and a definite end, right there, physically on the page: things happen in the order they are written, and you can't make that kind of mistake.

Comment: Yes and while I'm adding new API health-check tasks, the list of tasks could be running the network checks and Combine could be publishing the results to my DashboardView. That's my solution. Thanks Matt.